# Привет ребят я не понимаю я верно вожу код на джава нажимаю кнопку run и мне пишет что код верный но сообщение не воспроизводится

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("hello word"); 
}
```

}

Comment: а где ты смотришь сообщение? в консоли IDE? А можешь полный код привести?

Comment: да сейчас отправлю

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что ваша строка запускается из основного метода main.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello word"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: public class Demo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("gh");
    }
}